# Embed Google-Site Image in email (Gmail)

Tags: image, gmail, google-sites

I am trying to embed an image (under `<img src=.../>`) in an email (Gmail). The image is a photo stored in another Google Site (not owned by me). Because Google-Site stores the image files without extension like `png` or `jpg`, though while composing the email the image is being displayed but actually when sent the Gmail server cannot display the image.

Is there any work around I can first get the photo URL with `jpg` or `png` and then link the image in my email and send properly?